# Is there an optimizing assembly compiler?

Tags: c, assembly

This may sound silly, but is there an optimizing assembly compiler? Like gcc or MSVC would optimize C.

Or at least is there a usable decompiler that produces compilable C? The code doesn't need to be readable. I just want to `asm -> c -> gcc -O3 -> ELF/PE`.

NOTE1: Maybe I should explain why I need this, after seeing a downvote. So there is a FreeBASIC compiler that produces the executable directly, but the compiler doesn't optimize well enough. I don't know why they didn't choose C as an intermediate representation. Perhaps I can rewrite the compiler to produce C, but not really now. It's trivial at least in Linux to produce the assembly from the executable, so I was thinking maybe there is a way to optimize this automatically.

Comment: What's your actual problem? Where does your assembly code come from?

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); please **edit your question to improve it** and tell the motivations and context.

Comment: What is your FreeBASIC source code doing? What is its size?

Comment: I finally downvoted the question, because it obviously lacks research efforts. When using a free software which does not satisfy you, your first reflex should be to get the latest source code and study it (then improve it and share your patch).

Comment: It is certainly possible to write one but it might break the code.  backends of compilers will have a peephole optimizer which optimizes a little once you get to the target specific stuff (After the generic front and middle of the compiler).  Say for example your source was C and you had a volatile keyword on a variable, that produces inefficient code which an assembly level optimizer might remove...breaking the original code...or other reasons why a compiler or hand made assembly would have inefficient code that the optimizer couldht/wouldnt know about generically.

Comment: @dwelch: yeah, you'd have to be really conservative with re-ordering memory accesses to maintain correctness in the general case.  If you had a re-compiler, you could have an option to assume the code was single-threaded (and that there weren't signal handlers, either).  Then the re-compiler could assume that all functions followed the ABI, and modify them in ways that left non-callee-save regs in a different state, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and it probably cannot exist in the general case (but it might exist, and did exist in the past -1990s- for some MIPS or Sparc workstations, if the assembler code is somehow restricted). You might try to use some [decompiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler) (but these cannot reliably work on every code, in particular, because not every assembler code is expressible in C, and because a compiler is losing some information from its source code), and then recompile with optimization the decompiled C code.

BTW, you really need some optimizing FreeBASIC compiler (e.g. code your FreeBASIC to C - or to LLVM - translator). Perhaps (if your FreeBasic program is not big) you might instead translate (by hand, perhaps with the help of some script) your FreeBASIC source into something else.

At last, [FreeBASIC](http://www.freebasic.net/) is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (GPLv2 licensed). You could spend some (months or years) of effort to improve it, and make it [generate either C](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065), or LLVM code, or use [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) or [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/JIT) just-in-time compilation libraries. 
I personally believe that it is not worth the effort, because BASIC is a nearly dead language (and there are lots of languages better than BASIC: Ocaml, Haskell, Common Lisp, Clojure, Scala, Scheme, Go, D, ....; and the existing living source code base in BASIC is not that big today)

It looks like the `FreeBASIC-1.02.1-source/` (as provided by the [FreeBASIC-1.02.1-source.tar.gz](http://ttps://downloads.sourceforge.net/fbc/FreeBASIC-1.02.1-source.tar.gz) archive) contains a `inc/llvm-c.bi` & a `src/compiler/ir-llvm.bas` files, so probably already has some work to generate LLVM. You should investigate (and ask LLVM to optimize more).

<sup>Notice that I never used FreeBASIC and probably never will. But I do have the habit of looking inside free software source code, and you should get that habit too...</sup>

Comment: That does exist, see my answer.

Comment: I mentioned and explained the *general case*

Comment: I don't see how it doesn't work in the *general case.* The Plan 9 assemblers are fairly general and don't restrict how you write your assembly.

Comment: I already have a working C program, I just translated some parts of this C program to FreeBASIC because I really like its syntax. But the FreeBASIC compiler isn't good enough in optimizing. Probably the best option for me is to write my own FB to C compiler. The translating script you mentioned is what I call a compiler.

Comment: @xiver7, yes, sort of. But hopefully the semantics of your FreeBASIC is similar enough to C. And if your FreeBASIC source code is small enough, translating it by hand to C (or to D, or to C++, or to Go) might be easier than coding a small FreeBASIC to C compiler

Comment: Don't lose your time in learning and using FreeBASIC. If you don't like C syntax, learn some other language (Ocaml, Haskell, Common Lisp, Clojure, Scala, D, Go, Ada, ....); but IMHO BASIC is nearly dead.

Comment: I love C and its syntax. The syntax of FreeBASIC matches very much to C and C++, and it supports (almost?) everything that C does in clean syntax.

Comment: You can write an OS with FreeBASIC. http://wiki.osdev.org/FreeBasic_Bare_Bones

Comment: So what? You can write an OS in Haskell, Ocaml (look into [MirageOS](https://mirage.io/)...), Go, ...

Comment: FreeBasic has an native (x86) and a C code backend (called CGEN, gcc based). Afaik the LLVM effort was aborted.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The compiler infrastructure of the Plan 9 operating system uses assemblers and linkers that do various optimizing tasks usually performed by the compiler like:

- instruction selection (unsupported instructions are emulated)
- register allocation (partially)
- dead code elimination
- some peephole optimization

See [here](https://golang.org/doc/asm) for an introduction into the Go flavour of Plan 9 assembly.